# Extract only the first and last date from a list of files including date in their name in R

Tags: r, excel, readr, readxl

I have a list of excel files which I load into R, and then bind all together.

This is the code I use to load in the files

```
setwd("T:/file/path")
file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.xlsx')
list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel)
df <- rbindlist( list )
```

I then run the code below to subset the files on specific conditions, and write this out to a new csv file.

```
events <- df %>%
  filter(intent == 2 | str_detect(text_info, 'SI'))

write_csv(events, "Notifications year_month_day_year_month_day.csv")
```

Each of the files I load in is called "Notifications year_month_day-year_month_day.xlsx"

What I would like to do is extract the dates from the file names, find the earliest and latest date, and append this information to the name of the csv file which I output. This way I wouldn't have to manually enter the earliest and latest date to the new file name.

In the real data I'm working with, `file.list` looks like this:

```
file.list
[1] "Notifications 20200104-20200110.xlsx"                
[2] "Notifications 20200111-20200117.xlsx"                
[3] "Notifications 20200118-20200124.xlsx"                
[4] "Notifications 20200125-20200131.xlsx"                
[5] "Notifications 20200201-20200207.xlsx"                
[6] "Notifications 20200208-20200214.xlsx"
```

I'm looking for code which could
a) extract the dates from the file names
b) sort them in order
c) take the earliest and latest date

The output of this would be `20200208_20200110`

and then I would like to append these dates to the file name specified in this code

```
write_csv(events, "Notifications year_month_day_year_month_day.csv")
```

Comment: Why is it `20200208` and `20200110` and not `20200104` and `20200214` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
paste(
    rev(format(range(
                as.Date(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(file.list, '\\d+')),
             '%Y%m%d')), 
        '%Y%m%d')), 
   collapse = "_")

#[1] "20200214_20200104"
```

`str_extract_all` extracts all the numbers from `file.list`, we `unlist` them to get as a vector, convert them to date, use `range` to get min and max date, use `format` to get data in required format, reverse them and paste together.